# failing to do fb like to postId I have just shared successfully

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have shared a url from my android app to FB:

I then save aside (hard coded) the postId

I try to do "fb like" to that post

using this code, but get an error:

```
Button socialBtn3 = (Button) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.socialBtn3);
                socialBtn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    String fbPostId = "685560152_10153809399380153";
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        new LikeFbPostAsyncTask().execute(fbPostId);
                    }
                });
```

and this:

```
public class LikeFbPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    public LikeFbPostAsyncTask() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("LikeFbPostAsyncTask", "Starting web task...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... fbPostId) {

        Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                fbPostId + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
                new Request.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

                        // how to return to ui thread?
                        // return response;
                    }
                });
        Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {

    }
}
```

> {Response:  responseCode: 404, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   404, errorCode: 803, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803)
>   Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:
>   [Ljava.lang.String;@4284cd10}, isFromCache:false}

how can i solve this?

Comment: I don't think you here need the `AsyncTask` because facebook `execBatchandWait` also execute the request in the asynchronous manner.

Comment: how can i know this for next time? where is this written for sure?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant

Comment: other than that, how can i solve my problem?

Comment: where could i verify `execBatchandWait also execute the request in the asynchronous manner`

Comment: oh, yep `executeBatchAndWait` run on the current thread !. See here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Request/#executeAndWait%28%29

Comment: and make sure your network connectivity did not break while your request was in progress. Try it again and make ensure your post id is also correct

Comment: i have tried few times. how can I verify my post id is correct? that's what I have received after posting on fb wall from my app.

Comment: Try to use datatype of post id long over the string, it might work

Comment: cannot, look at the id: `685560152_10153809399380153 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending an array of String arguments to the AsyncTask (`String...`).
When extracting the desired string from the array you should do :

```
    Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
            fbPostId[0] + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
            new Request.Callback() {
```

instead of:

```
Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
        fbPostId + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {
```